# Aggregate in R based on variable condition

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to create a new variable called REF_YEARCPI that aggregates the CPIs for all 12 months within the year. In the table, there is a variable called REF_MONTHCPI but I need to transform this variable into an annual variable (called REF_YEARCPI) that aggregates 12 of the CPI values within the year. In the image, I have 2 columns: REF_MONTHCPI stores the monthly reference periods and CPI_RESTAURANT which stores the CPI for the month.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to have better chances to get a good answer (and not downvotes and/or closed question).

Comment: Try `df1$REF_MONTHCPI-1) %/% 12 + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the name of the dataframe you have so I will assume it as df.

```
df$REF_YEARCPI <- df$REF_MONTHCPI * 12
```

You can replace df in the above code with the name of your dataframe.